# Обновление данных в таблице используя DataTable C# Postgres

Tags: c#, база-данных, postgresql

Нужно выполнить обновление записей в таблице в субд Postgres,

Получаю все данные из таблицы с заданным именем table_name,

[image: Таблица до изменения]

Изменяю данные в таблице (не обязательно вставка, может быть и обновление)
[image: Таблица после изменения]

Как выполнить обновление таблицы в базе, если известно только имя таблицы.

Была идея сделать Merge запрос, для объединения всех записей, но не понятно как его сделать. (Можно конечно по названиям столбцов брать и собирать запрос, но хотелось бы сделать лучше)

Данные хранятся в DataTable, в гугле не нашел как из этой структуры обновить базу.

Для работы с базой использую библиотеку NpgSql

Comment: Как данные попадают в `DataTable`? Вручную или с применением `DataAdapter`/`TableAdapter`? Если вручную, то также самостоятельно нужно делать апдейт: пробегаем по строкам, проверяем их версию, измененные отправляем в БД. Если используется адаптер, то нужно задать у него правильный запрос в `UpdateCommand`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  Да, действительно с помощью DataAdapter и CommandBuilder удалось выполнить обновление через Update у  DataAdapter , предварительно заполнив все запросы с помощью CommandBuilder